# What does it mean if the bumper is not firmly attached to the rest of the body?

Tags: body, bumper

I saw a few cars where the bumper was not closely attached to the rest of the body:

[image: Toyota Yaris front bumper]
[image: Honda Jazz back bumper]
[image: Suzuki Swift front bumper]
[image: Honda Fit back bumper]

I have a few ideas on what could possibly cause this:

1. The bumper somehow became loose without any accident.
2. There was an accident and the bumper was repaired.
3. There was an accident and the bumper was replaced.

Which of these scenarios (or others) can cause the bumper to appear like this?

Comment: If they are on a dealer's forecourt that you are considering buying: walk away.

Comment: There is a fourth possibility; Poor quality during original construction.;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking at is not actually the bumper but rather the bumper cover.  It's a plastic shell that covers the bumper itself and is relatively fragile.

The one you are showing may have been removed and then improperly re-installed or it may have been damaged somehow but it's not the bumper.  If you were to remove it you would see the actual bumper which is generally steel or aluminum and is firmly connected to the body of the car.

Comment: In Europe we very much do not have hard metal bumpers underneath, not for some years. The plastic thing *is* the bumper and is supposed to collapse relatively slowly on impact, to protect pedestrians in low-speed collisions. Cars can be repaired or replaced more easily.

Comment: Thanks for the useful Information, but it does not really answer my question. What I am asking is: Can this become loose by itself without a car accident? In case the bumper was repaired or replaced, is it possible for this to be the result, or is it easy for people who do such repairs to fix it properly?

Comment: I did answer your question: "It may have become damaged somehow..."  I suppose it may have been installed improperly at the factory as well but generally they catch that at the factory or at the dealer.

Comment: And lets not forget about thermal expansion and plastic bumper covers (typically called fascias). The difference in fascia “width” can vary greatly (10 to 12 mm) or so between hot weather and cold weather.

Comment: If I understand correctly, all 3 possibilities I provided in my question are valid possibilities. And there is also a 4th, least likely possibility, that it was manufactured improperly.